# MYSQL select mulitiple fields / columns from the table's row that are not empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have 12 columns on the below code and I want the best, correct and short way to select only fields for a user order(a row)  where the field is not empty/0 in the table.(all fields are INT and numbers are less than 500)

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","table_name") or die("error");
               $sql = "SELECT dqnt_91,deal_91,dqnt_92,deal_92,dqnt_93,deal_93,dqnt_94,deal_94,dqnt_95,deal_95,dqnt_96,deal_96 FROM table_name  WHERE fid='$userid' AND COLUMNS ARE NOT EMPTY ";  

                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
               $d_91 = $row['deal_91'];  $d_92 = $row['deal_92']; $d_93 = $row['deal_93'];  $d_94 = $row['deal_94']; $d_95 = $row['deal_95'];  $d_96 = $row['deal_96'];
               $qnt_91 = $row['dqnt_91']; $qnt_91 = $row['dqnt_92']; $qnt_91 = $row['dqnt_93']; $qnt_91 = $row['dqnt_94']; $qnt_91 = $row['dqnt_95']; $qnt_91 = $row['dqnt_96']; }
  echo 'You have selected:'.$d_91.'for'.$deal_91.'<br>';
  echo 'You have selected:'.$d_92.'for'.$deal_92.'<br>';

echo 'You have selected:'.$d_96.'for'.$deal_96.'<br>';
```

Again, I want echo out only those fields that are not zero(0) or empty and if they are zero value then don't show or echo them!
The code below can work but because I have 12 columns and can add more to them then the below code is not handy.

```
SELECT [ all 12 x columns_name] FROM table_name WHERE table_name.column_name1!='' AND table_name.column_mame2!='' AND x another 10 times the last code ;
```

Thanks,

Comment: what might the output look like, based on what input?

Comment: text like : You have selected 98 for 22 , also echo is echo 'You have selected:'.$dqnt_91.'for'.$deal_91.'

Answer (score 0):

Short of modifying the data structure, you won't do much better in SQL than listing the 12 columns each with its own condition; and anything shorter will come at a cost of clarity, so personally I'd advise against it.  But if brevity is more important than clarity for your application:

If you can add a view, it could provide a simple flag for you to test against.

```
create view my_view as (select -- each column
                             , case when -- all values are present
                                    then 1 else 0 end nonempty_flg
                          from -- ...)
```

Then at least the complexity is hidden away from the calling app.  If that's not an option:

You state the columns are small integer values.  If you can further assume they're non-negative, then you can sum them up and compare against 0.  If the might be negative, you could sum their absolute values.

In your examples the columns are treated as strings.  If they are in fact CHAR or VARCHAR, you could concat them all and check the result against empty.  You might have to coalesce null values to '' as you go.

But it sounds like what you *really* want is something that works without the query knowing in advance the set of columns; that's not doable in SQL.  I suppose you could write a function/method/procedure in your calling program to generate the query based on examining the table columns in the catalog.

Comment: Thanks, there are no negative value and I can set the column to VARCHAR (no problem if that helps) or I can also replace the numbers into text if that comes in handy. Based on that, what do you suggest and do you think that an if ...else  can comes in handy?

Comment: I'm not sure what you'd do with an `if...else`, but I can't say it *won't* help without knowing what you have in mind.  What I suggest... well, like I said, I suggest just listing a separate condition for each column because in SQL that's the direct representation of the logic.  If your needs call for doing something different then you'll have to evaluate what trade-off is best.